# qss: how to get QTreeView bottom border to appear under the branch subcontrol

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qtstylesheets

I have a QTreeView in my application, where I need to draw borders around every cell.
If I set my style like this:

```css
QTreeView::item
{
    border-right: 1px solid #6d6d6d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6d6d;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
}
```

The border does not appear under the branch sub-control:
[image]

If I set the border on the branch area:

```css
QTreeView::branch
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6d6d;
}
```

Then the branch image (triangle) disappears.
[image]

Ideally, I would like to set the border from the style.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: image and background-image work for branches and can be combined with border-image:

```css
QTreeView::branch
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6d6d;
}
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children 
{
    image: url(:/img/collapsed);
}
QTreeView::branch:open
{
    image: url(:/img/expanded);
}
```